# Adding Validation to a Dynamically constructed form

Tags: forms, validation, angular, typescript, primeng

### Scenario

---

I am developing a savedialog which accepts any simple object with string, boolean and date fields. I've constructed a component which handels the construction of this, now I would like to dynamically add validation to the input fields which have been created.

I'm programming in TypeScript, using Angular2 and Also a framework called PrimeNG which is the Angular2 version of PrimeFaces.

### My code at the moment

**Html**

```
<p-dialog #dialog header="{{dialogTitle}}" [(visible)]="isDisplayed" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade"
      [modal]="true" [closable]="false" [closeOnEscape]="false" [modal]="true" [width]="1000" [resizable]="false">
<form novalidate #form (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid" *ngIf="saveObject">
        <div *ngFor="let i of rows" class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-6" *ngFor="let field of fields | slice:(i*itemsPerRow):(i+1)*itemsPerRow">
                <div class="ui-grid-col-5 field-label">
                    <label for="attribute">{{field.key}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-col-5">
                    <p-checkbox *ngIf="booleanFields.indexOf(field.key) !== -1" binary="true"
                                [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]" name="{{field.key}}"
                                [ngClass]="{'error-border-class': field.key.errors && (field.key.dirty || field.key.touched)}"
                                [valueValidator]="field.key" [validateObject]="saveObject"></p-checkbox>
                    <p-calendar *ngIf="dateFields.indexOf(field.key) !== -1" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]"
                                name="{{field.key}}"
                                [ngClass]="{'error-border-class': field.key.errors && (field.key.dirty || field.key.touched)}"
                                dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [showIcon]="true" [appendTo]="dialog"
                                [monthNavigator]="true"
                                [ngClass]="{'error-border-class': field.key.errors && (field.key.dirty || field.key.touched)}"
                                [valueValidator]="field.key"
                                [validateObject]="saveObject"></p-calendar>
                    <input *ngIf="(booleanFields.indexOf(field.key) === -1) && (dateFields.indexOf(field.key) === -1)"
                           pInputText id="attribute" [(ngModel)]="saveObject[field.key]" name="{{field.key}}"
                           [ngClass]="{'error-border-class': field.key.errors && (field.key.dirty || field.key.touched)}"
                           [valueValidator]="field.key" [validateObject]="saveObject"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <p-footer>
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
            <button label=" " type="button" pButton (click)="hideDialog(true)">
                <i class="fa fa-times fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sluit
            </button>
            <button label=" " type="submit" pButton (click)="hideDialog(false)" [disabled]="!form.valid">
                <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Opslaan
            </button>
        </div>
    </p-footer>
```

**SaveDialogComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnChanges, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldUtils } from '../utils/fieldUtils';
import { ValueListService } from '../value-list/value-list.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'save-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'savedialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['savedialog.component.css']
})
export class SaveDialogComponent implements OnChanges {

@Input() dialogTitle:string;

@Input() isDisplayed:boolean;

@Input() saveObject:any;

@Input() unwantedFields:string[] = [];

@Input() booleanFields:string[] = [];

@Input() dateFields:string[] = [];

@Output() hide:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

@Output() result:EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<any>();

private fields:any[];

private itemsPerRow:number = 2;

private rows:any[];

ngOnChanges() {
    this.fields = FieldUtils.getFieldsWithValues(this.saveObject, this.unwantedFields);
    this.rows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.fields.length / this.itemsPerRow)).keys());
}

hideDialog(clearChanges:boolean) {
    if(clearChanges){
        this.resetObject()
    }
    this.isDisplayed = false;
    this.hide.emit(this.isDisplayed);
}

save() {
    this.result.emit(this.saveObject);
}

private resetObject() {
    for(let field of this.fields) {
        this.saveObject[field.key] = field.value;
    }
}

private getDate(date:string):Date {
    return new Date(date);
}
}
```

I'm Not including field utils since this it isn't that important, basically It extracts all the fields from an object, uses the booleanFields and dateFields to order the fields inorder to place all the fields of a same type next to one another.

**ValidatorDirective**

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[valueValidator][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ValueValidatorDirective, multi: true}
    ]
})
export class ValueValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('valueValidator') fieldName:string;
    @Input() validateObject:any;
    @Input() values:any[];

    datumStartValidator:ValidatorFn;
    datumEindValidator:ValidatorFn;
    codeValidator:ValidatorFn;
    naamValidator:ValidatorFn;
    volgNrValidator:ValidatorFn;

    validate(c:FormControl) {
        this.instantiateFields();

        switch (this.fieldName) {
            case 'datumStart':
                return this.datumStartValidator(c);
            case 'datumEind':
                return this.datumEindValidator(c);
            case 'code':
                return this.codeValidator(c);
            case 'naam':
                return this.naamValidator(c);
            case 'volgnr':
                return this.volgNrValidator(c);
            default :
                return {
                    error: {
                        valid: false
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    instantiateFields() {
        this.datumStartValidator = validateStartDatum(this.validateObject['datumEind']);
        this.datumEindValidator = validateEindDatum(this.validateObject['datumStart']);
        this.codeValidator = validateCode();
        this.naamValidator = validateNaam();
        this.volgNrValidator = validateVolgNr(null);
    }
}

//We'll need multiple validator-functions here. one for each field.
function validateStartDatum(datumEind:Date):ValidatorFn {
    return (c:AbstractControl) => {
        let startDatum:Date = c.value;
        let isNotNull:boolean = startDatum !== null;
        let isBeforeEind:boolean = false;
        if (isNotNull) {
            isBeforeEind = datumEind.getTime() > startDatum.getTime();
        }

        if (isNotNull && isBeforeEind) {
            return null
        } else {
            return returnError();
        }
    }
}

function validateEindDatum(startDatum:Date):ValidatorFn {
    return (c:AbstractControl) => {
        let eindDatum:Date = c.value;
        let isNotNull:boolean = eindDatum !== null;
        let isBeforeEind:boolean = false;
        if (isNotNull) {
            isBeforeEind = eindDatum.getTime() > startDatum.getTime();
        }

        if (isNotNull && isBeforeEind) {
            return null
        } else {
            return returnError();
        }
    }
}

function validateCode():ValidatorFn {
    return (c:AbstractControl) => {
        let code:string = c.value;

        if (code !== null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return returnError();
        }
    }
}

function validateNaam():ValidatorFn {
    return (c:AbstractControl) => {
        let naam:string = c.value;

        if (naam !== null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return returnError();
        }
    }
}

function validateVolgNr(volgnummers:string[]):ValidatorFn {
    return (c:AbstractControl) => {
        return returnError();
    }
}

function returnError():any {
    return {
        error: {
            valid: false
        }
    }
}
```

## My problem

First of all I want to say thank you for reading this all the way, you're a champ! I know my code is not the most well writen beautiful code you've ever seen but I'm just trying to get it to work at the moment. The problem I have at the moment is that Validation happens but I can't seem to set the class using

```
[ngClass]="{'error-border-class': field.key.errors && (field.key.dirty || field.key.touched)}"
```

field.key is found no problem But I don't seem to be able to use that as reference to the dynamic name given to the input fields. field.key.errors is undefined which I guess is to be expected. But I haven't found how to fix this yet.

Secondly I think that the way I have It now I'm going to end up having trouble with the validation of the entire form (to disable the submit button)

```
<button label=" " type="submit" pButton (click)="hideDialog(false)" [disabled]="!form.valid">
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this are welcome, I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at https://formstate.github.io/. Angular forms aren't particularly type friendly. Recommend MobX / React 